# JQuery function doesn't fire in ejs

Tags: javascript, jquery, ejs

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {
    alert( "ready!" );
    $('#dropDown').click(function() {
    console.log("run");
    var selected = $('#dropDown').find(":selected").text();
    console.log(selected);
    });
});

</script>

<div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <h1 class="page-header">
                    <center>Benchmark Usage</center>
                </h1>
            </div>
            <!-- /.col-lg-12 -->
  </div>
<div class="row" data-ng-controller="">
<div class="col-md-12">

<select id="dropDown">
<option value="day">every day</option>
<option value="minute">every minute</option>
</select>

<iframe src="http://vgzeburt55:5601/goto/517982d9d05378bac8368b4bf91338fe?embed=true" height="710" width="100%"></iframe>
</div>
</div>
```

I was trying to get selected text through jquery. However, even the ready alert doesn't show up. Am I missing something? Also, am I trying to get the selected text in the correct way?

Comment: Any console errors?

Comment: @Taplar Nothing shows up in console

Answer (score 1):

Bind `on('change'` event.

**Working example:**

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {
    alert( "ready!" );
    
    $('#dropDown').on('change', function() {
      alert( this.value );
      console.log("run");
    var selected = this.value;
    console.log(selected);
    })

    
});

</script>

<div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <h1 class="page-header">
                    <center>Benchmark Usage</center>
                </h1>
            </div>
            <!-- /.col-lg-12 -->
  </div>
<div class="row" data-ng-controller="">
<div class="col-md-12">

<select id="dropDown">
<option value="day">every day</option>
<option value="minute">every minute</option>
</select>

<iframe src="http://vgzeburt55:5601/goto/517982d9d05378bac8368b4bf91338fe?embed=true" height="710" width="100%"></iframe>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: He says he's not even getting the `alert("ready")`, so the code never runs. What difference does the event make?

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't your jquery src have **https:** prefix?

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: No, it shouldn't. If you leave out the protocol, it uses the same protocol as the original page.

Comment: But if he's trying to load the page from a local file instead of a webserver, this would indeed be the problem.

Comment: That would explain why my local file test didn't work without it :-)

Comment: I added the https at the front but nothing happens

Comment: Strange, because I copied and pasted all of your code inside <!DOCTYPE HTML><html><body> tags and saved it as "test.html" to my desktop. The "ready!" alert pops up for me.

Comment: @JohnMitchell My file is saved as ejs. Could that be the problem?

Comment: I never used EJS. But after quickly researching it, I can see a nice tutorial on how to use it with Node.js here http://www.giantflyingsaucer.com/blog/?p=4241 . So I suppose it depends on how you are using the EJS, and do you have the header tags included somewhere? (<DOCTYPE HTML> etc).
Sorry I couldn't be of more help, I hope you get it sorted. I think I should do that tutorial myself :-)